# MS Access .Movenext / .moveprevious

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I am attempting to use `tblReceipts` variable as a recordset, which works, and it is set in the form_load, but when I try to use it in the move next and move previous buttons, it says the variable isn't set, it seems like it initializes the variable, but only for the form load, but doesn't carry through the rest of the code, is there a way to make it public?

The error I get is: error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim tblReceipts As Recordset
Set tblReceipts = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tblReceipts]", dbOpenDynaset)

tblReceipts.MoveFirst
Me.RecieptID.Value = tblReceipts![ReceiptID]
Me.RefNo.Value = tblReceipts![ReferenceNumber]
Me.TrackingID.Value = tblReceipts![TrackingNumber]
Me.CustID.Value = tblReceipts![CustomerID]
Me.CustPostcode.Value = tblReceipts![CustomerPostcode]

End Sub


Private Sub btnNext_Click()

MsgBox "There are no more records to show", vbOKOnly, "End of file"

Exit Sub

If tblReceipts.EOF Then

Else

tblReceipts.MoveNext
Me.RecieptID.Value = tblReceipts![ReceiptID]
Me.RefNo.Value = tblReceipts![ReferenceNumber]
Me.TrackingID.Value = tblReceipts![TrackingNumber]
Me.CustID.Value = tblReceipts![CustomerID]
Me.CustPostcode.Value = tblReceipts![CustomerPostcode]

End If


End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated and I will try to answer any questions.

Comment: declare tblReceipts as global.

Comment: The variable is global, and is accessible through the code, but I set it's value (to the receipts table) in form_load, but this doesn't carry through the rest of the code

Comment: Nope, your variable is declared inside the Form_Load, it is not global. Move the `Dim tblReceipts As Recordset` line outside the Form_Load sub.

Comment: You can't move Dim tblReceipts As Recordset out of the form_load, I have Public tblReceipts As Recordset under option compare database, outside of form_load

Comment: Quick question - why there is a `Exit Sub` before If condition in sub `btnNext_Click`? Pointing to that in which line of code are you getting the error?

Comment: Oh I fixed that, forgot to mention that, but thank you for pointing it out, was meant to be in the if statement, the issue is, when I access the tblReceipts variable, it isn't set to a table, it gets set in the form_load, and works perfectly in the form_load, but when I try and access and use the variable after, it is no longer set the the table, and so throws run-time error 91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Public tblReceipts As Recordset under option compare database, outside of form_load

But you also have

```
Dim tblReceipts As Recordset
```

**inside** `Form_Load()`. And local variables have precedence over global variables, so what gets set here is the local variable.

Remove the `Dim` statement from `Form_Load()`.